# Combining Image Maps and On Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, imagemap

I'm trying to create functionality where if a user hovers over a section of an image map, an image and text is displayed in a separate div within the same page.

I'm ok with the HTML and CSS, however I'm unsure of how to write the jquery script.

Comment: I haven't tried anything in relation to jquery. I've only built the image maps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a JS library like ImageMapster (http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/). They have a demo doing something very similar (http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#beatles).